# Create a large .csv (or any other type!) file with google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I've been struggling to create a file with GAE for two days now, I've examined different approaches and each one seems more complex and time consuming than the previous one.

I've tried simply loading a page and writing the file in to response object with relevant headers:

```
self.response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=titles.csv"
q = MyObject.all()
for obj in q:
    title = json.loads(obj.data).get('title')
    self.response.out.write(title.encode('utf8')+"\n")
```

This tells me (in a very long error) that `Full proto too large to save, cleared variables.` Here's the [full error](http://pastebin.com/eaYeYF3Y).

I've also checked Cloud Storage, but it needs tons of info and tweaking in the Cloud Console just to get enabled, and Blobstorage which can save stuff only in to the DataStore.

Writing a file can't be this complicated! Please tell me that I am missing something.

Comment: That message is not the error, it's just telling you it can't save the log to appstats. Please post the actual error.

Comment: Plus, it's completely untrue that blobstore "can only save stuff to the datastore". It saves to the blobstore.

Comment: @DanielRoseman posted link to the full error code

Answer (score 1):

That error doesn't have anything to do with writing a CSV, but appears to be a timeout when iterating over all MyObject entities. Remember that requests in GAE are subject to strict limits, and you are probably exceeding those. You probably want to use a cursor and the deferred API to build up your CSV in stages. But for that, you definitely will need to write to the blobstore or CS.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Would you happen to have any examples of writing a file to Blobstore? Because the snippets here:https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/ only show how to upload files from a webpage

Comment: Well the docs for that are [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Python_Writing_files_to_the_Blobstore) but looks like it's deprecated in favour of writing to GCS. Really, you should probably do that, it's not complicated.

Comment: What broke me what the fact that I had to create 2 (!!!) billing profiles, in 2 different places to enable GCS for one (!!) project. Like someone's trying really hard to keep people from using that feature.

Comment: @MeLight This blob post will help you to create csv file & store it in blobstore: http://www.sapsico.com/2013/12/Create-and-Save-CSV-file-to-Google-Appengine-Blobstore